# SCCM 2012: Past due - will be retried

Tags: deployment, sccm

I think I'm missing something regarding deployment scheduling and deadlines in SCCM 2012 R2.

I have created an uninstall script for an application that runs interactively.
So user action is required because the uninstall of that software will cause other pograms to stop responding.

The uninstall works flawlessly.
Users have the option to postone the uninstall 5x.
After they've postpone the fifth time the uninstall will be forced.

Now here is the problem...
I have deployed this to a device collection as **Required**.
When users postpone the uninstall, in software center it shows "**Past due - will be retried**".
No big deal because when i run it manually in software center again, I see what I have to see and I can again choose to postpone or do the uninstall now.

The Problem is that I have to manually go to the Software Center and hit "Install" to start the script.

Why is manual action required?
I have made it Required. Shouldn't SCCM push the application by itself at certain intervals?

**Settings of deployment:** 
Installation deadline:"As soon as possible after the available time"

In User experience...
On this window, under "When the installation deadline is reached, allow the following activities to be performed outside the maintenance window" I checked "Software Installation"
"Commit changes at deadline or during a maintenance window" is also checked.